# bertFoR classification (task nl2sql)

Tags: rasa

give me the code pour développer un chatbot en utilisant le model bert sur le framework rasa et avec le dataset WikiSQL , ce chatbot transforme une requete naturelle en requete sql , le nom du model bert c'est "bert base uncased"